# GDS Amadeus setup cost

Tags: planning, gds

I need some information about GDS systems, preferably Amadeus. I am currently not that far along my research path that I can officially contact Amadeus about it.

Assuming I am setting up my own travel agency, using a GDS would for my operations would be the way to go. Is this right or is a GDS just a nice-to-have?

If I am to use it, what would be the basic setup cost? I understand that this is quite a broad question as Amadeus bundles individual packages to best fit the customers needs. Therefore some numbers from people with experience in that field would suffice.

Thanks in advance for the answers!

Comment: I am not sure whether questions about running a travel agency are on-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about running a business

Comment: It is not so much about running a business as it is about the GDS. And that corresponds more to the travel category, in my opinion. But since I am interested in an answer, if the chances are higher in some other category, I would gladly appreciate your advice.